# Webscrape LinkedIn Users

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

Goal is to scrape information from people/users

Here is my code - Trying to get into the url to eventually scrape data from the search.

However when executing the code, it prompts the log in page. This is where im currently stuck

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
productlinks=[]
test1=[]

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


url = "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?currentCompany=%5B%221252860%22%5D&geoUrn=%5B%22103644278%22%5D&keywords=sales&origin=FACETED_SEARCH&page=2"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-email')
username.send_keys('example123@gmail.com')
password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-password')

password.send_keys('Password123')
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-submit')
log_in_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 methods

1. Add the login code logic in your code by clicking the login button and send the login credentials using `send_keys()`
2. Disable headless by removing `options.headless = True` and manually login yourself
3. Since LinkedIn uses cookies to validate session, so you can login once and store up the cookies somewhere else and inject back to your session every time you launch selenium driver.

   For getting the cookies,

   ```
   # Go to the correct domain
   driver.get("https://www.example.com")
   # get all the cookies from this domain
   driver = browser.get_cookies()
   # store it somewhere, maybe a text file
   ```

   or do it manually and copy from Chrome Dev Tools

   For restoring the cookies

   ```
   # Go to the correct domain
   driver.get("https://www.example.com")
   # get back the cookies
   cookies = {‘name’ : ‘foo’, ‘value’ : ‘bar’}
   driver.add_cookies(cookies)
   ```

Reference: [LinkedIn Cookies Policy](https://www.linkedin.com/legal/cookie-policy#:%7E:text=We%20use%20two%20types%20of,Services%20without%20signing%20in%20again.)

Comment: how many days this cookies are valid do you know